# How to open a specific imageView item from ViewPager without looking at scrolling to the item?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I use viewPager.setCurrentItem(position) for opening a specific imageView item from my ViewPager.

This method works and It shows me the necessary imageView according to its position, but before I notice the image view on my screen I have to look at pretty fast slide which I want to hide.

How can I do this?

One of the solutions I made up in my mind was to use timer to load a view pager on the background while being invisible to the user. Though 0.3 seconds is quite fast I want to find a more elegant way if it exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra argument to the method to set the smoothScroll as false.
`viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)`

Comment: I feel kinda silly that I did not notice the simplest step to make it happen. Thank you so much!!!